# How to represent calls within same class using UML-Sequence diagram

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I am trying to create UML sequence diagram for a particular process in our application.

The problem is that most of the business logic is in one class and when I try to map it in sequence diagrams, I am getting multiple calls to the same objects in the sequence diagram.

What I need is a representation similar to a stacktrace in UML sequence diagram. Is it possible using sequence diagram or is some other diagram a better way for representing calls within the same class? 
Please advise.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A few suggestions:

1. You can show successive methods on a sequence diagram using self calls.  See Figure 1 [here](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/sequenceDiagram.htm) for an example (self calls are the circular invocations on the same lifeline).
2. As an alternative you might consider an [Activity Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram).  Possibly better suited for illustrating order of methods.
3. Refactor the code.  Lots of logic in a single class is usually a bad smell.  Assuming you have the scope, refactoring might be a good idea.

hth.

Comment: +1. Right, "Activity Diagram" its better for methods in the same object.

Answer (score 15):

Representing a self-call on a UML sequence diagram (see step 7).

[image: self-call on a UML sequence diagram]

If the called method is (or should be) private, then it can safely be excluded from the sequence diagram as an implementation detail.

However I smell the [God-Class](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GodObject) anti pattern; your class has multiple responsibilities and should be deconstructed.  Break down the class so that is has only a [single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) using delegation.  Those method calls would be a good starting point.

Comment: I limit my classes to one method per class, so that this issue cannot happen by design. Every class has the single responsibility of executing one method, and it makes unit testing way simpler because every class is an implementation of an interface that can be mocked.

Comment: Ah yes, having `Increment()` and `Add(int)` on the same class is _totally_ an anti-pattern. /s

Answer (score 3):

It is actually possible to refer to the self instance

In fact UML spec 2.5b1 page 607, about a Lifeline is said: *If the name is the keyword self, then the Lifeline represents the object of the classifier that encloses the Interaction that owns the Lifeline. Ports of the encloser may be shown separately even when self is included.*

See https://web.archive.org/web/20131101211441/http://lowcoupling.com/post/47844944042/uml-sequence-diagrams for a complete example

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: Here's the archive.org mirror of that link from 2013 https://web.archive.org/web/20131101211441/http://lowcoupling.com/post/47844944042/uml-sequence-diagrams